# Websocket exhausted on Azure App Service Standard S1 plan?

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We've updated from Basic to Standard for our two instance App Service apps, and I'm getting this warning:

[image: Websocket exhasted on Standard Azure plan]

Based on this the Standard plan should have unlimited websocket?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#app-service-limits

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: That seems like sockets connections are being leaked. I would suggest a code review unless you expect many sockets connections to be made.

Answer (score 2):

Unlimited in this case means that there is not going to be any artificial throttling of your site. However, a physical machine is only capable of handling a certain number of sockets before it runs out, and at the end of the day every instance of your site is running on just that, a physical machine.

If you're running out of sockets either try scaling out your site to multiple instances or better yet take a closer look at your application to see if there are ways to reduce the number of sockets simultaneously in use.